# NameExpr cannot be converted String

Tags: java

I am trying to get package name but i get an error

Error:
incompatible types:NameExpr cannot be converted String

```
String packagePrefix = cu.getPackage().getName();
```

I tried to convert "getPackage().getName()" to string with toString() method following code:

```
String packagePrefix = cu.getPackage().getName().toString();
```

And i get following error:

```
Error:cannot find symbol:method.toString()
location:class NameExpr
```

Probably NameExpr class doesn't contain toString() method depending on this question:[What does a "Cannot find symbol" compilation error mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25706216/what-does-a-cannot-find-symbol-compilation-error-mean)
How can i fix this problem?

Edit:
Full Code:

```
 public static String parseClassname(File filename) throws Exception {
        try (FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(filename)) {
            CompilationUnit cu = JavaParser.parse(fin);
            String packagePrefix = cu.getPackage().getName().toString();
            if (!packagePrefix.isEmpty()) packagePrefix += ".";

            for (TypeDeclaration type : cu.getTypes())
            {
                if (type instanceof ClassOrInterfaceDeclaration) 
                return packagePrefix + type.getName();    

            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: What is cu in your code?

Comment: it means there is something wrong, it can't find the toString() method, but since that's inherited from Object ..

Comment: It would be really helpful if you'd provide a [mcve] here.

Comment: check the type returned by getName()

Comment: getName returned NameExpr and i cannot convert this name to string.I expected to getPackage().getName() return a package name(string) and it didn't return string